# How can I populate a 3-slide carousel from the DB with many pages and an undefined amount of data

Tags: python, loops, carousel

I have this html-carousel that displays 3 items at a time and then has an arrow to pass to the next 3 slides.

[image]

I need to populate this slides from my DB. The DB will always be growing so it has to be dynamic. It has to not only populate the slides but calculate how many '3-slides-pages' the carousel needs to be able to fit all the data.

My data comes as a list of tuples and every tuple is destined for a slide. (The first 3 tuples fit in the first page of the carousel, the next 3 tuples should go to the second page of the carousel).

Im struggling with the python loops and can't figure it out.

I hope I explained it well, but I'll post the html for the carousel so you get an idea. (Right now its hard coded to have 2 pages with 3 slides each)

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 1
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 2
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 3
                            </div>       
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 4
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 5
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                tuple 6
                            </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it.

```
row_len = 3
for i in range(0, len(data), row_len):
    for elem in data[i:i+row_len] :
        print(elem)
```